# XPath to get all child nodes (elements, comments, and text) without parent

Tags: xml, xpath

I need an XPath to fetch all ChildNodes ( including Text Element, Comment Element & Child Elements ) without Parent Element. Any help

Sample Example:

```
<DOC>
<PRESENTEDIN>
    <X>
        First Text Node #1 
        <y> Y can Have Child Nodes # 
            <child> deep to it </child> 
         </y>
         Second Text Node #2 <z/> 
    </X>
    <EVTS>
        <evt/>
        <evt>
            <mtg_descr> SAE 2006 World Congress &amp; Exhibition </mtg_descr>
            <sess_descr> Advanced Hybrid Vehicle Powertrains (Part 1 of 5) </sess_descr>
            <loc> Detroit,MI,United States </loc>
            <sess_prod_grp_cd> TSESS </sess_prod_grp_cd>
            <sess_evt_name> P13 </sess_evt_name>
            <sess_gen_num> 138352 </sess_gen_num>
            <mtg_start_dt> 04/03/2006 </mtg_start_dt>
            <mtg_end_dt> 04/06/2006 </mtg_end_dt>
            <desig> CONGRESS-2006 </desig>
        </evt>
    </EVTS>
    <EVTTYPE>PAPER</EVTTYPE>
    <SUPERTECH>
        <![CDATA[C8585]]>
    </SUPERTECH>
</PRESENTEDIN>
```

XPATH TRIED

```
   1. $doc/PRESENTEDIN/X
   2. $doc/PRESENTEDIN/X/descendant::*
   2. $doc/PRESENTEDIN/X/self::*
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
    First Text Node #1 
    <y> Y can Have Child Nodes # 
        <child> deep to it </child> 
     </y>
     Second Text Node #2 <z/>
```

I DON'T WANT

```
<X>
  First Text Node #1 
        <y> Y can Have Child Nodes # 
            <child> deep to it </child> 
         </y>
         Second Text Node #2 <z/> 
</X>
```

Answer (score 93):

From the documentation of XPath ( http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths ):

> `child::*` selects all element
>   children of the context node
>
> `child::text()` selects all text node
>   children of the context node
>
> `child::node()` selects all the
>   children of the context node, whatever
>   their node type

So I guess your answer is:

```
$doc/PRESENTEDIN/X/child::node()
```

And if you want a flatten array of all nested nodes:

```
$doc/PRESENTEDIN/X/descendant::node()
```

Comment: Correct but do also check the [Abbreviated Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)

Comment: I'm using this to copy all child nodes, but on the output each child element is stamped with a namespace identifier; any way to disable that?

Comment: Also, the slash before "child::" indicates one level down, two slashes indicates more than one level down.

Answer (score 29):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
/*/*/X/node()
```

This selects any node (element, text node, comment or processing instruction) that is a child of any `X` element that is a grand-child of the top element of the XML document.

**To verify what is selected**, here is this XSLT transformation that outputs exactly the selected nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/X/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and it produces exactly the wanted, correct result:**

```
   First Text Node #1            
    <y> Y can Have Child Nodes #                
        <child> deep to it </child>
    </y>            Second Text Node #2 
    <z />
```

**Explanation**:

1. **As defined in the [W3 XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths)** Spec, "`child::node()` selects all the children of the context node, whatever their node type." This means that any element, text-node, comment-node and processing-instruction node children are selected by this node-test.
2. `node()` is an abbreviation of `child::node()` (because `child::` is the primary axis and is used when no axis is explicitly specified).

Comment: @Spiderman, Yes, should we be nostalgic? Now we have XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1