# how to catch an array of nodes to a property

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can any one please let me know how can I access an array of elements to a property.

For example: I have an XML as said below

```
<a>
 <x>1</x>
 <x>2</x>
 <x>3</x>
 <x>4</x>
</a>
```

I want my property to be set as shown below:

```
 <x>1</x>
 <x>2</x>
 <x>3</x>
 <x>4</x>
```

when I try to access using //x with property type set to OM element or String I don't see the result as expected in my property.

Can any one please direct me with the right xpath to be used to see the desired outcome ?

Comment: Can you provide your code of your accesss to the propery also? I mean where you apply the //x. Thanks

Comment: Its the same, im providing //x only. Off-course //namespace:x

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use //a/child::node() XPath for this.

Please refer [XPath to get all child nodes (elements, comments, and text) without parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119655/xpath-to-get-all-childnodes-and-not-the-parent-node)

Hope this helps!!

/Harshana