# Get all elements in IWebElement using XPATH

Tags: c#, selenium

I've tried using webelement(and IWebElement) and string lists, but i keep getting errors. How I do get a list or strings of all the elements text by XPath? I have all Selenium references. Do i need some java.util dll? Should I implement a foreach loop?

Comment: what errors? `"i've tried"`.. could you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: public List<String> policy1Details = new List<String>();public void PolicySummary1(int i)
{
    policy1Details.Clear();
            
    //var psummary = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class,'discount-list')]/li"));
    var psummary = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='PolicyDetails_" + i + "']/div/table"));
    foreach (iwebelement d in psummary)
    {
        policy1details.add(d.text);
    }

}

Comment: Based on your provide code snipet, you used wrong code to return a list of  objects. That's the reason why you have exception/error.

Comment: Why would you need  java.util dll in C# project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to do but you can get element text using following code.

```
  public List<String> policy1Details = new List<String>();
    public void PolicySummary1(int i)
    {
        //var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        policy1Details.Clear();
        var psummary = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//text()"));//give your xPath.

        //var psummary = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='PolicyDetails_" + i + "']/div/table"));
        foreach (IWebElement d in psummary)
        {
            //resultText.Add(d.Text);
            policy1Details.Add(d.Text);
        }
    }
```

if any issue the let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the topic with a similar question! - [XPath to get all child nodes (elements, comments, and text) without parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119655/xpath-to-get-all-child-nodes-elements-comments-and-text-without-parent)

And here is the quote from there!

> child::* selects all element children of the context node

So you can do the:

```
var childs = parent.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));
```

Also here is the [documentation of XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths), you can read more here!