# xQuery Array[*]?

Tags: sql, xml-parsing, db2, xquery, xquery-sql

```
SELECT
    XMLQUERY    ('$x/test/xml[1]/data(@type)' PASSING XMLCOLUMN as "x") type,
    XMLQUERY    ('$x/test/xml[1]/text()' PASSING XMLCOLUMN as "x") text
FROM 
    XML
```

I want to select all child-nodes of a parent-node. I am thinking about something looking like this:

```
SELECT
    XMLQUERY    ('$x/test/xml[*]/data(@type)' PASSING XMLCOLUMN as "x") type,
    XMLQUERY    ('$x/test/xml[*]/text()' PASSING XMLCOLUMN as "x") text
FROM 
    XML
```

edit:
xml:

```
<test>
    <xml type = 1>a</xml>
    <xml type = 2>b</xml>
    <xml type = 3>c</xml>
    <xml type = 4>d</xml>
    <xml type = 5>e</xml>
    ...
</test>
```

expected result:

```
type | text
-----|-----
1    | a
2    | b
3    | c
4    | d
...
```

Comment: Direct child nodes or all? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119655/xpath-to-get-all-child-nodes-elements-comments-and-text-without-parent and if you are returning multiple columns, I recommend XMLTABLE instead

Comment: XMLQUERY    ('$x/xml[*]/child::node()' PASSING XMLCOLUMN as "x") text
gives me the same result

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: i edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following, based on XMLTABLE:

```
select t.* from x,   
       xmltable('$X/test/xml'
          columns "type" int path 'data(@type)',
                  "text" varchar(10) path 'text()') as t
```

It should return a table with the desired values and structure.