# Retrieve value and attribute name from xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this block of xml.

```
    <procedure>
        <name1>first</name1>
        <name2>second</name2>
        <name3>third</name3>
    </procedure>
```

How can I retrieve the values (first, second, third - this I can do) and attributes (name1, name2, name3) as an XPath Expression?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and show what exactly is your expected output. Also, what version of xpath can you use?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve values 'first', 'second' and 'third' you can use below x-path.

```
//procedure/*
```

Also you can get each value separately.

```
//procedure/name1
//procedure/name2
//procedure/name3
```

name1, name2, name3 are the nodes and these are not attributes.
You can use below x-path to get node name.

```
//procedure/*/name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python's module [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/):

```py
import lxml.html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = """<procedure>
        <name1>first</name1>
        <name2>second</name2>
        <name3>third</name3>
    </procedure>"""

    root = lxml.html.fromstring(text)

    for item in root.xpath('./descendant::node()'):
        try:
            if item.strip():
                print(item)

        except AttributeError:
            print(item.tag)
```

Pay attention to the xpath expression used, as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5119937/6328506) SO answer.

The code above prints:

```
name1
first
name2
second
name3
third
```

You just have to save it in a `.py` file and execute it with: `python3 script.py`.

Comment: I can't use python, only an XPath Expression, because I am using Opentext Appworks. Thank you, though.

Comment: Try the expression `.//procedure/descendant::node()`